# How to return character of font family given index

Tags: c#, fonts

I have a font family name and an index of a specific character from that family.

Example: I have the font family "Wingdings 2" and index 33. If you go to http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings-2.html and look at the first item, which is  index 33, the character is a ball point pen.

My question is, how can I retrieve the character itself in C#? I need to draw this character in my application.

I've gone through all of the methods and properties of the Font and FontFamily class, but I don't see anything that could help.

Edit: I know how to draw the character using a graphics object, the issue is actually retrieving the character in the first place knowing only the font family and the index of the character in the given font family.

Comment: can't you just use a graphics object and a string representing only that character and draw it anywhere you want?

Comment: I know how to to draw stuff, the problem is getting the character to draw knowing only the font family and the index of that character in the font family.

Answer (score 1):

To draw a character you could use this snippet of code:

```
public static Image DawTextFromFontFamily(string text, FontFamily family, Color textColor, Color backColor)
{
     return DrawText(text, new Font(family, 16), textColor, backColor);
}

public static Image DrawText(String text, Font font, Color textColor, Color backColor)
{
        //first, create a dummy bitmap just to get a graphics object
        Image img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
        Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

        //measure the string to see how big the image needs to be
        SizeF textSize = drawing.MeasureString(text, font);

        //free up the dummy image and old graphics object
        img.Dispose();
        drawing.Dispose();

        //create a new image of the right size
        img = new Bitmap((int)textSize.Width, (int)textSize.Height);

        drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

        //paint the background
        drawing.Clear(backColor);

        //create a brush for the text
        Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);

        drawing.DrawString(text, font, textBrush, 0, 0);

        drawing.Save();

        textBrush.Dispose();
        drawing.Dispose();

        return img;
}
```

Now you have an image of whatever characters in whatever font you need

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but not quite what I need. I know how to to draw stuff, the problem is getting the character to draw knowing only the font family and the index of that character in the font family.

Comment: well for the Fontfamily you can just create a font https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6xaya1yk(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think I was confused about how fonts work here. I used Convert.ToChar(CharacterIndex), then applied the font family and it seems to be working now :)